# Question about whether there is a unique functional in Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

In Linear Algebra Done Right, on page 188, it states the Riesz Representation Theorem.

> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $\varphi$ is a linear functional
>    on $V$. Then there is a unique vector $u\in V$ such that $\varphi(v) =
>  \langle v,u \rangle$.

So clearly once we have a linear functional, there's a unique $u$. Is this true in reverse? If I have a unique $u \in V$, does this assure me a unique $\varphi \in V'$ (V dual)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The map $u\longmapsto \langle \cdot,u\rangle$ is a (linear) bijection from $V$ onto $V^*$. If $u_1$ and $u_2$ give the same functional, you have $\langle v,u_1\rangle=\langle v,u_2\rangle$ for all $v\in V$; we may write this as $\langle v,u_1-u_2\rangle=0$ for all $v$, in particular for $v=u_1-u_2$ and we get $u_1=u_2$. So the map is injective. The surjectivity of the map is precisely the Riesz Representation Theorem.

The interesting thing is that this works also in infinite dimension, when $V$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is the subjectivity of the map the Riesz Representation Theorem? I am assuming by "the map" in this sentence you mean $u \mapsto \langle \cdot, u \rangle$? Isn't showing surjectivity of this map trying to show that every possible $\varphi \in V^\star$ exists? I'm not quite following this part.

Comment: Surjectivity, the way I wrote it, is that given any $\varphi\in V^*$ there exists $u\in V$ such that $\varphi(v)=\langle v,u\rangle$ for all $v\in V$. That's precisely what the Riesz Representation Theorem says.